# Android: Drawing walking routes

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, kml, kmz

I'm making an android app which let users choose a specific walking route, my questions is (since I've heard I can use kml files for this) How do I use kml files in my map fragment(Using maps v2)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=es

You can use it within maps V2.

Regards

Comment: Well, I'm using this at the moment, but what I try to achieve is that people upload a kml file to the server and my app can download that file to draw a route. I don't know if that is possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your KML File, you need to parse your KML and then create your own objects (eg. Polygons, Lines, Markers, etc.) to draw them using Google Maps API.